# How to set <PrivilegedApplications> tag in device metadata?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, metadata, windows-store-apps

Im working on a windows 8 store application so as to send an sms. I have the code running but the i get an error saying "Access Denied" and that my application does not have enough privileges.

Is there any way for me to create my own app (which uses the sms capabilities of the device) and test it out without having to register it with Windows Hardware Dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was able to find out :

So by using this process of "Sideloading", you can install apps directly to a device without having to go through the windows store. I will provide the links that got me going in this project,

**[Sideloading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832040.aspx#BKMK_SideLoad)**

**[Discussions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows?query=side-load&rq=meta:Search.MSForums.GroupID%287df09344-598d-4d00-80ea-51b8d79f051a%29%20site:microsoft.com&rn=All%20Windows%208%20IT%20Pro%20Forums)**

**[Creating the Metadata](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/05defdcd-1658-41cb-8d77-235ecfd194db)**

**Edit:** WDK 8.1 now comes with a new Metadata Authoring tool that is easier/simpler to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that you need to add the capability to the manifest for your application. If you want to take a look at this, download the sample here (pick any language):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sms-SendReceive-fa02e55e

What you're looking for is the SMS capability in the manifest. It looks like it doesn't show up in the VS designer, but you can see it in the raw XML. Open the project, and in solution explorer, right click on package.appxmanifest. Then click view source. Near the bottom of the manifest, you'll see this:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="Sms" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Try adding that to your application's manifest. I suspect that's what you're missing.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Ben, Thanks. I already did this, i suspect this has something to do with the device metadata.